# MySQL - ZERO date inserted instead of default date

Tags: mysql

I have a pipe delimited file with some NULL date fields. I load this data into a temp table with default values for NULL dates. In my case, I wish to default to 1950-01-01. However, these defaults are seemingly being overwritten and 0000-00-00 is being inserted. Here is a quick bash script I wrote to test:

```
#!/bin/bash

CMD="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ar_tmp LIKE ar; LOAD DATA INFILE '/some/path/ar.txt' INTO TABLE ar_tmp FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'; SELECT * FROM ar_tmp;"

mysql -uuser -ppassword db -e "$CMD" > /opt/rxdb/tmp.log
```

I have grepped my source file and confirmed the expected NULL dates have \N and no where in the file is the pattern 0000-00-00.

Here is the structure of ar_tmp:

```
Field                   Type            Null    Key     Default Extra
customer_code           int(11)         NO      PRI     0
activity_date           date            NO      PRI     1950-01-01
delivery_date           date            NO      PRI     1950-01-01
sequence                int(11)         NO      PRI     0
type                    varchar(10)     YES             NULL
due_date                date            YES             1950-01-01
original_charge         float           YES             NULL
prior_alloc             float           YES             NULL
current_alloc           float           YES             NULL
future_alloc            float           YES             NULL
open_balance            float           YES             NULL
shipto_customer         int(11)         NO      MUL     0
reference               varchar(10)     YES             NULL
journal_ref_number      int(11)         YES             NULL
next_month_flag         int(11)         YES             NULL
journal_type            varchar(15)     YES             NULL
activity_num            int(11)         YES             NULL
document_path           varchar(100)    YES             NULL
conditional_eft_approved char(1)        NO              N
customer_name           varchar(30)     YES             NULL
allow_web_payment       char(1)         YES             NULL
modify_date             datetime        NO              1950-01-01 12:00:00
```

The defaults being over road are activity_date, delivery_date and due_date. Can someone explain what is going on?

**EDIT:**

Three lines from the source file:

```
5830|2012-02-21|\N|29543|PAYMENT|\N|-600.5|0|0|0|-600.5|5830|505700|4807|0|Cash|0||N|TIME WARNE|N|2012-03-09 07:07:11
8057|2012-03-08|\N|32523|PAYMENT|\N|-1348.74|0|-1348.74|0|0|8057|1486|22|0|Cash|0||N|PACIFIC HA|N|2012-03-09 07:07:11
8103|2012-03-07|\N|32138|PAYMENT|\N|-1382.29|0|-1382.29|0|0|8103|3719|4|0|Cash|0||N|NORTH COUN|N|2012-03-09 07:07:11
```

Corresponding resultant records:

```
5830    2012-02-21      0000-00-00      29543   PAYMENT NULL    -600.5  0       0       0       -600.5  5830    505700  4807    0       Cash    0               N       TIME WARNE      N       2012-03-09 07:07:11
8057    2012-03-08      0000-00-00      32523   PAYMENT NULL    -1348.74        0       -1348.74        0       0       8057    1486    22      0       Cash    0               N       PACIFIC HA      N       2012-03-09 07:07:11
8103    2012-03-07      0000-00-00      32138   PAYMENT NULL    -1382.29        0       -1382.29        0       0       8103    3719    4       0       Cash    0               N       NORTH COUN      N       2012-03-09 07:07:11
```

Comment: What's the date format used on your input file?

Comment: What happens with an explicit `ESCAPED BY '\\'`?

Comment: @Wrikken: I've modified the query to be FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ESCAPED BY '\\'; and am receiving this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''\'; SELECT * FROM ar_tmp' at line 1. Pardon my ignorance but what's wrong with that syntax?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I'm sorry, 1 extra escape is needed for the bash thingamyig: `ESCAPED BY '\\\';` (we're aiming for an explicit `\ ` as escape, but when several layers are involved, alwyas tricky how many `\ `s one needs ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `\N` is being transformed into an empty string, then the `INSERT` command will use it, and the DEFAULT value will be ignored.

I mean with this:

```
INSERT INTO table(customer, date) VALUES ("123", "")
```

then `date` will contain `0000-00-00`. For the default value to be used, nothing should be passed for the date at all:

```
INSERT INTO table(customer) VALUES ("123")
```

Comment: I was going to post that exact answer, after testing. I'm not sure, but I think SQL Server would behave differently in this case: if a column is not nullable, it inserts the default value when you pass NULL. The way MySQL behaves looks a little odd...

Comment: This appears to be exactly the case, thank you for posting. I will update if I find a solution using LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: I'm happy it helped. Edited the answer a bit, because I did some tests and when trying to pass NULL value to a non-null column, MySQL rejected it throwing an error.

Comment: @bfavaretto - MySQL can operate in a "strict" mode and in a "relaxed" mode, with slightly different behaviours

Comment: @J. Bruni: Can you elaborate on this a little? I've been reading about strict mode and there may be a way to not allow 0000-00-00 date values.

Comment: If you turn strict mode on, with "NO_ZERO_DATE" turned on or "ALLOW_INVALID_DATES" turned off, then 0000-00-00 will not be allowed, but you will lose the entire row, because the command will throw an error. Details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/faqs-sql-modes.html

Answer (score 1):

Your table probably allows null values to be inserted for modify_date, which results in a value of '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for datatime fields  The column in your infile is present, but empty in some cases.  When the infile is loaded, it treat the column as existing but without a value, treating it as null, hence value of '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

Edit the infile and delete the column.  If values actually set for some records and you can't delete the field,  you'll need to manually add '1950-01-01 12:00:00' to the records in the file without anything specified.

Comment: modify_date does not allow for NULL values and defaults to 1950-01-01 12:00:00.